# Unimodular lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, integer-lattices

We are considering $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the inner product (the usual one), and $L$ an unimodular lattice (so $covolume(L)=1$ and $<u,v> \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all u,v in L).

I have to show that, for $n \geq 4$, we can find $v \in L$ such that : $<v,v>=1$. Then, there is some intermediary step, and finally we want to show that if $n \geq 4$, it exists $g \in O_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that : $L = g(\mathbb{Z}^n)$.

Actually, I didn't succeed to prove the first question about $<v,v>$. But for the final result, there is also something I don't understand. Just after, we are considering : $\mathbb{Z} \frac{1}{2}(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)  + \{ \; (x_1, ..., x_8) \in \mathbb{Z}^8 \; | \; x_1 + ... + x_8 = 0 \;(\mod 2) \; \}$, and we show that it's a unimodular lattice, but it's not of the form $g(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ for some $g \in O_n(\mathbb{R})$.

I think there is a contradiction right here... Does the result right for $n \geq 4$ or only $4 \leq n \leq 7$ ?

Thank you !